# Probability of sampling an element in this list

Tags: real-analysis, probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ be a list of $n$ distinct integers. Suppose we pick uniformly at random $k$ distinct elements from $A$ and call $B$ the list obtained. Now we sample one element $x$ uniformly at random from $B$. Let $A'$ be the input list $A$ but in sorted increasing order.

What is the probability of choosing $x$ as $i$-th term in $A'$ given that $x$ lies in the middle third of $B$?

This is my attempt. Assuming that $k$ is a multiple of 3 we can argue that the probability is 0 for $i= 1, 2, \dots, \frac{k}{3}$ and for $i = n, n - 1, \dots, n - \frac{k}{3}$. For any other case we can get

$$ \mathbb P(x \text{ is the $i$-th element in $A'$}) = \sum^{\frac{k}{3} - 1}_{j=0}\frac{{i - 1 \choose \frac{k}{3} + j}\times{n-i \choose \frac{2k}{3}- j - 1}}{n \choose k}$$

Is this correct? Is there a way to simplify or bound  this probability?

Comment: I maybe missing something obvious, please help to clarify. To me it seems that the process is equivalent to sampling $X$ uniformly random from $A$ directly, so the rank of $X$ follows a discrete uniform from $1$ to $n$. $X$ lies in the middle third if and only if the rank lies in the middle third of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. So that will be simply $1/3$ assuming there is is no round off.